# HtmlPurifier disformats input

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, htmlpurifier

i try to get htmlpurifier to work with my code as following:

```
if(isset($_POST['selectors_data'])) {
 //$selectors_data = tep_db_prepare_input($_POST['selectors_data']);
 $selectors_data2 = $_POST['selectors_data'];

 $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
 $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
 $selectors_data = $purifier->purify($selectors_data2);
}
```

i try to insert (**newvalue**): `<i class="fa fa-angellist"></i>`

*on my localhost all magic quotes and references to magic quotes are turned off*

When data is saved (via jQuery $.post )

```
$.post('ajax_editor.php', {
        action: 'update',
        selectors_id: id,
        selectors_field: field,
        selectors_data: newvalue
    }, function (data) {

        $(' #container ').html(data);

    }, "json");
```

Via the following query the data is told to insert:

```
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_BTS_CSS_SELECTORS . " set selectors_name = '" . $selectors_data . "' where selectors_id = '" . (int)$selectors_id . "'");
```

And via the following db function the data is actually inserted:

```
function tep_db_query($query, $link = 'db_link') {
global $$link;

$result = mysqli_query($$link, $query) or tep_db_error($query, mysqli_errno($$link), mysqli_error($$link));

return $result;
}
```

So, nothing is replaced/stripped/removed in the whole process except with htmlpurifier
But the data is stored as:

```
<i class=""fa"></i>
```

I am out of options.

As my site is in utf-8 i also tried:

```
 $purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
 $selectors_data = $purifier->purify($selectors_data2);
```

So without config

When i test on the [Htmlpurifier(click to see attempt)](http://bit.ly/1wduwH3) demo site , all seems fine.

UPDATE: i am now 100% sure the issue is NOT created by HTMLpurifier.There seems to be some hidden unknown code that converts `$_POST` statements (sorry)

**SOLVED** found the "hidden code as:

```
    // handle magic_quotes_gpc turned off.
  if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    do_magic_quotes_gpc($HTTP_GET_VARS);
    do_magic_quotes_gpc($HTTP_POST_VARS);
    do_magic_quotes_gpc($HTTP_COOKIE_VARS);
  }
```

Where ofcourse for each $_GPC or $HTTP_GPC slashes are add.
so a SIMPLE `stripslashes($_POST['selectors_data'])` BEFORE HTMLPurifier let it work :)

Sorry for the big post

Comment: perhaps multiple classes are not supported

Comment: just added link to demo site where can see it is supported.

Comment: are you sure that `<i class="fa fa-angellist"></i>` is the entire string passed to HTMLPurifier

Comment: yes and chars are converted to database as: `<i class="&quot;fa"></i>` should that not be just `<i class=""fa"></i>`  as the output

Comment: ok... i just did a "hardcode" test : `     if(isset($_POST['selectors_data'])) {
     //$selectors_data = tep_db_prepare_input($_POST['selectors_data']);
     $selectors_data2 = '<i class="fa fa-angellist"></i>';

  //$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
     $purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
     $selectors_data = $purifier->purify($selectors_data2);
    }`  and like that it worked

Comment: sorry i cannot get the code in my comment above nicely formated.

Comment: And we don't do "SOLVED" here.

Comment: I considered that, but it felt strange to make an answer pointing to a completely different code not related to HTMLPurifier, so in my mind i was try to keep in the SO spirit, just did not know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The script itself has code in it that acts as magic_quotes_gpc ON, so when it is detected that it is turned OFF in your server environment, the function is executed.

The solution in above specific case is a simple `stripslashes()` before the data will be inserted to database.

So HTMLPurifier does it job as supposed to.